# Number of hyperconjugation structures

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, hyperconjugation

Is the number of hyperconjugation structures for a hydrocarbon with number of 'alpha' hydrogens 'a' equal to 'a' or 'a+1'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use the n-propyl carbocation as an example.  It has **two** hydrogens alpha to the cationic carbon and **two** resonance structures involving hyperconjugation of those alpha hydrogens can be drawn.

[image]

Comment: So total number of structures are 3 or 2 as itself is also a structure?

Comment: Total number of resonance structures is 3

Comment: What about the analogous structure using the C-methyl bond instead of the C-H bond?

Comment: Yes, resonance structures incolving C-C hyperconjugation are also valid resonance structures.  In this case, C-C hyperconjugation probably contributes less to the overall picture of the molecule than C-H hyperconjugation. I didn't include such structures since the OP was asking about the alpha-hydrogens.